# What is the standard way to write scripts to manipulate a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

It seems that psql has no branching, and doesn't support PL/pgSQL blocks either.  How do people automate Postgres database actions?  Should I write functions, and just call the functions from psql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.0 and up lets you execute an anonymous code block using a [DO statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html).

If you need to support earlier versions of Postgres, you could, within a transaction, create a stored procedure, execute it, and delete it.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like just the thing.  The project is currently on 8.3 but I can upgrade.

Comment: looks like i misunderstood the question. I thought it was about psql and missing pgsql features in there. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

psql is just a client that you can use to interact with postgresql server. pl/pgsql is executed in the server and can be added/altered using psql (or any other client).

Maybe you find more on what you're looking for here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql.html